# Where does this "no data" warning come from? (cursor loop)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE INPUT ( NUM INT );
INSERT INTO INPUT VALUES (1);
CREATE TABLE OUTPUT ( NUM INT );

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_LOOP()
BEGIN
  DECLARE NUMBER INT;

  DECLARE DONE TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE REC CURSOR FOR SELECT NUM FROM INPUT;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET DONE = 1;

  DELETE FROM OUTPUT;

  OPEN REC;
    L: LOOP
      FETCH REC INTO NUMBER;
      IF DONE = 1 THEN
        LEAVE L;
      END IF;

      INSERT INTO OUTPUT VALUES (NUMBER);
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE REC;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I then ran `CALL TEST_LOOP();`, the procedure runs as expected (one record in OUTPUT table) but produces a warning says:

```
No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed.
```

Where does the warning come from?

Comment: Warning comes after procedure execution completes.

Comment: sorry, my question is actually asking why the warning occurred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually [an active bug in MariaDB](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-4602) that is originating from MySQL 5.5.

From the [MySQL 5.5 manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/condition-handling.html);

> Before MySQL 5.6.3, if a statement that generates a warning or error causes a condition handler to be invoked, *the handler may not clear the diagnostic area*. This might lead to the appearance that the handler was not invoked.